# How to make -autosize- and -behave- work togheter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, autosize

I am trying to design an html textarea for programmers where 2 plugins work on.

It seems for some reasons they exclude each other.

These plugins are:

- [autosize](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/)
- [behave](http://jakiestfu.github.io/Behave.js/)

This is my code:

```
<head>

    <!-- jquery inclusion -->
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

    <!-- auto-resize inclusion (type: mime) -->
    <script src="http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=iEEZptfL"></script>

    <!-- behave text-indent inclusion (type: mime) -->
    <script src="http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=T2SjtM33"></script>

    <!-- initialize behave -->
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {

            // here, enable autosize plugin
            // comment follow line will make behave to work
            $('#textarea').autosize();

            // here, enable behave plugin
            var editor = new Behave({

                textarea: $('#textarea')[0],

                replaceTab: true,
                softTabs: false,
                tabSize: 4,
                autoOpen: true,
                overwrite: true,
                autoStrip: true,
                autoIndent: true,
                fence: false

            });

        });

    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="text-area">

        <textarea id="textarea"></textarea>

    </div>

</body>
```

Until here, it seems everything is included and everythis is written correctly.

When I try to use the textarea, `behave` works (try to write a bracked `(` and it completes the other one `)`), but `autosize` isn't active.

When I comment `behave` out, `autosize` starts to work permitting the area to be resized when cursor reaches bottom limit.

where is the conflict?

thank you!

Comment: This code work in FF and Chrome. Maybe some other plugin is problem

Comment: Yes, currently it works but just one of two plugins work at the same time. I don't know how can I make both work. It seems they manage same events but I can't get where to start to debug